# Is perl's each function worth using?

Tags: perl, hash, iterator, each

From [perldoc -f each](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/each.html) we read:

> There is a single iterator for each hash, shared by all `each`, `keys`, and `values` function calls in the program; it can be reset by reading all the elements from the hash, or by evaluating `keys HASH` or `values HASH`.

The iterator is not reset when you leave the scope containing the `each()`, and this can lead to bugs:

```
my %h = map { $_, 1 } qw(1 2 3);
while (my $k = each %h) { print "1: $k\n"; last }
while (my $k = each %h) { print "2: $k\n"       }
```

Output:

```
1: 1
2: 3
2: 2
```

What are the common workarounds for this behavior? And is it worth using `each` in general?

Comment: I would imagine that common workarounds include evaluating `keys HASH` or `values HASH`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I think it is worth using as long as you are aware of this.  It's ideal when you need both key and value in iteration:

```
while (my ($k,$v) = each %h) {
    say "$k = $v";
}
```

In your example you can reset the iterator by adding `keys %h;` like so:

```
my %h = map { $_ => 1 } qw/1 2 3/;
while (my $k = each %h) { print "1: $k\n"; last }
keys %h;  # reset %h
while (my $k = each %h) { print "2: $k\n" }
```

From Perl 5.12 [`each`](http://search.cpan.org/~shay/perl-5.11.5/pod/perl5120delta.pod#each_is_now_more_flexible) will also allow iteration on an array.

Answer (score 8):

I find `each` to be very handy for idioms like this:

```
my $hashref = some_really_complicated_method_that_builds_a_large_and_deep_structure();
while (my ($key, $value) = each %$hashref)
{
    # code that does stuff with both $key and $value
}
```

Contrast that code to this:

```
my $hashref = ...same call as above
foreach my $key (keys %$hashref)
{
    my $value = $hashref->{$key};
    # more code here...
}
```

In the first case, both `$key` and `$value` are immediately available to the body of the loop. In the second case, `$value` must be fetched first. Additionally, the list of keys of `$hashref` may be really huge, which takes up memory. This is occasionally an issue. `each` does not incur such overhead.

However, the drawbacks of `each` are not instantly apparent: if aborting from the loop early, the hash's iterator is not reset. Additionally (and I find this one more serious and even less visible): **you cannot call `keys()`, `values()` or another `each()` from within this loop**. To do so would reset the iterator, and you would lose your place in the while loop. The while loop would continue forever, which is definitely a serious bug.

Answer (score 8):

`each` is too dangerous to ever use, and many style guides prohibit its use completely.  The danger is that if a cycle of `each` is aborted before the end of the hash, the next cycle will start there.  This can cause very hard-to-reproduce bugs; the behavior of one part of the program will depend on a completely unrelated other part of the program.  *You* might use `each` right, but what about every module ever written that might use your hash (or hashref; it's the same)?

`keys` and `values` are always safe, so just use those.  `keys` makes it easier to traverse the hash in deterministic order, anyway, which is almost always more useful.  (`for my $key (sort keys %hash) { ... }`)

Comment: use a lot of global hashes, do you?

Comment: Doesn't matter if it's global or not.  Even private attributes of a class are vulnerable to this problem.  Anything that returns a reference to a hash is affected.

Answer (score 7):

each is not only worth using, it's pretty much mandatory if you want to loop over all of a tied hash too big for memory.

A void-context keys() (or values, but consistency is nice) before beginning the loop is the only "workaround" necessary; is there some reason you are looking for some other workaround?

Comment: Excellent point!  This is the best (only?) reason to use `each` I can think of.

Answer (score 2):

use the [`keys()`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/keys.html) function to reset the iterator. See the [faq](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlfaq4.html#How-do-I-reset-an-each()-operation-part-way-through%3f) for more info

Answer (score 2):

`each` has a buit-in, hidden global variable that can hurt you.  Unless you need this behavior, it's safer to just use `keys`.

Consider this example where we want to group our k/v pairs (yes, I know `printf` would do this better):

```
#!perl

use strict;
use warnings;

use Test::More 'no_plan';

{   my %foo = map { ($_) x 2 } (1..15);

    is( one( \%foo ), one( \%foo ), 'Calling one twice works with 15 keys' );
    is( two( \%foo ), two( \%foo ), 'Calling two twice works with 15 keys' );
}

{   my %foo = map { ($_) x 2 } (1..105);

    is( one( \%foo ), one( \%foo ), 'Calling one twice works with 105 keys' );
    is( two( \%foo ), two( \%foo ), 'Calling two twice works with 105 keys' );
}


sub one {
    my $foo = shift;

    my $r = '';

    for( 1..9 ) {
        last unless my ($k, $v) = each %$foo;

        $r .= "  $_: $k -> $v\n";
    }
    for( 10..99 ) {
        last unless my ($k, $v) = each %$foo;

        $r .= " $_: $k -> $v\n";
    }

    return $r;
}

sub two {
    my $foo = shift;

    my $r = '';

    my @k = keys %$foo;

    for( 1..9 ) {
        last unless @k;
        my $k = shift @k;

        $r .= "  $_: $k -> $foo->{$k}\n";
    }
    for( 10..99 ) {
        last unless @k;
        my $k = shift @k;

        $r .= "  $_: $k -> $foo->{$k}\n";
    }

    return $r;
}
```

Debugging the error shown in the tests above in a real application would be horribly painful.  (For better output use `Test::Differences` `eq_or_diff` instead of `is`.)

Of course `one()` can be fixed by using `keys` to clear the iterator at the start and end of the subroutine.  If you remember.  If all your coworkers remember.  It's perfectly safe as long as no one forgets.

I don't know about you, but I'll just stick with using `keys` and `values`.

Answer (score 1):

It's best if used as it's *name*: **`each`**. It's probably the wrong thing to use if you mean "give me the first key-value pair," or "give me the first two pairs" or whatever. Just keep in mind that the idea is flexible enough that each time you call it, you get the *next* pair (or key in a scalar context).

Answer (score 1):

each() can be more efficient if you are iterating through a tied hash, for example a database that contains millions of keys; that way you don't have to load all the keys in memory.