# perl loop hash using each keyword on foreach loop

Tags: perl, hash, foreach

I tried to loop through a hash using each on a for each loop. Looks like the $k $v is not updated. Can anyone explain?

```
%hash = (a=>5,b=>6);
foreach( my ($k,$v) = each %hash){
    print "\neach loop : $k $v\n";
}

output :
each loop : a 5
each loop : a 5
```

Answer (score 4):

`foreach` takes a list of values, and executes its loop body once per value, assigning some variable (`$_` if otherwise unspecified) each time:

```
foreach ( 1, 2, 3 ) {
  print "The value is $_\n";
}
```

In your case, you gave it a list of two things, being the first key and value taken from the hash. Additionally, you also assigned those two new variables, `$key` and `$value` to be the key and value. Thus, your loop executed twice, with those variables remaining constant throughout.

A better way to iterate keys and values from a hash is to iterate on the list of keys, taking a value each time:

```
foreach my $key ( keys %hash ) {
  my $value = $hash{$key};
  ...
}
```

Alternatively, you might enjoy the `pairs` function from `List::Util` version 1.39:

```
foreach my $pair ( pairs %hash ) {
   my $key   = $pair->key;
   my $value = $pair->value;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Use the `while` loop.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;
my %hash = (a=>5,b=>6);
while (my ($key, $value) = each %hash) {
          print "Key is $key, value is $value\n";
}
```

[**Demo**](http://ideone.com/x948w6)

Also see: [Is perl's each function worth using?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2396511/is-perls-each-function-worth-using)

Comment: Hi Thanks for the code. I would like to know why using the foreach loop does not work as expected.

Comment: @LeoNerd has explained that in his answer.

Answer (score 1):

You need to do `while` instead of `foreach`:

```
my %hash = (a=>5,b=>6);
while( my ($k,$v) = each %hash){
    print "\neach loop : $k $v\n";
}
```

However, `each()` has [gotachas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2396511/is-perls-each-function-worth-using) that you need to be aware of, so I prefer just using `keys` instead, like this:

```
for my $k (keys %hash) { my $v = $hash{$k};  }
```